# Using Alexa to parse English to SQL using user input from a web app

Tags: javascript, sql-server, laravel, nlp, alexa-skills-kit

I am wondering if it is possible to convert English to SQL by using Alexa to process it. I want to let users type information such as 'cars within the zip code 12345 that are red' and have it query my sql-server database.

My ideal workflow is:

```
1. User input on web app is sent to Alexa
2. Alexa processes the sentence
3. Alexa sends it to server backend for processing
4. Server output displays on screen
```

I've researched this for a while and it seems that it is possible using the Alexa Skills Kit but that would be for using an Alexa device directly. I am interested in only using the processing logic for Alexa.

Essentially, I want to switch the input to Alexa from voice to user input on a web app. If this isn't possible, then I am open to any other approaches to my problem.

Comment: 4. Which display? Of the app? Or Echo Show or something?

Comment: It will display on the web app. The user will input something they want to search for and press enter / search. Then, they will be shown what they searched for in some data format. But it will all be on the web app / web page.

Comment: So what Alexa has to do with it? If you want just NLU, you can use AWS Lex.

Answer (score 1):

As Tarlog pointed out in the comments, you are looking at the wrong service here. Amazon Alexa is designed specifically for the Echo devices. You can use Amazon Lex which is functionally similary to Alexa and can be embedded into your webpage/app.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/lex/